# Value inserted in global var not able to use outside the function

Tags: typescript, logic

I'm trying to access the value of var Login inside submit(), but not able to do so.Maybe because of race-condition.Why am I not able to access the value of var Login?
  Code :

```
class ABC {    
 Login : any;

 send(){
 this.preview.send().subscribe(
 (data =>{
  this.Login = data;
  console.log("This is the new list in send function",this.Login); //Printing value of this.Login
   })
 );

submit(value) {
 // let Log : any = this.Login_Object['login'];
  console.log('Inside submit function',this.Login);// Not printing value of this.Login
}
}
```

Comment: You need to bind the this parameter to the function. In the send function you are using an arrow function which binds this automatically. Otherwise you need to call function.bind in the constructor.

Comment: So...how can that be solved?

Comment: const submit = (value) => {...}

Comment: It says a class member cannot have const keyword

Comment: Replace it with public, protected, private or leave it out ;)

Comment: No use still same. But I got one clue  ,send() prints value after the value(undefined) of submit()

Answer (score 0):

Bind the this to the callback function:

```
send(){
 this.preview.send().subscribe(
 (data =>{
  this.Login = data;
  console.log("This is the new list in send function",this.Login); //Printing value of this.Login
   }).bind(this)
 );
```

Comment: So, I need to create a Login  var inside send() ?

Comment: If I remove this it says cannot find Name LoginValue, even if I declare var inside function